# How to get the current folder from a string containing a url?

Tags: php

basically i have a folder with php scripts and then in that folder i have another folder with scripts. I want to load the same header file in each folder's index.php script. The script to include is nav.php located in the inclues folder.

Tree

```
includes
   nav.php
Folder1
   header.php
   index.php
   Folder2
      index.php
```

i want to  do this:

```
if getcwd() = 'Folder2'{
    include('../../includes/nav.php');
}else{
    include('../includes/nav.php');
```

But the problem is getcwd() returns the whole path in a string but i just want the cur directory name. How can I cut the string specifically to the remove everything but the directory name. All solutions are good to know,but im particularly interested in the function for slicing a string in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See function:

```
basename
```

Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

```
basename( getcwd())
```

should return to you the folder name from the path.
Here is an example of basename and dirname:

```
#> pwd
/home/user
#> php
<?php
echo getcwd() . "\n" ;
echo dirname( getcwd()) . "\n" ;
echo basename( getcwd()) . "\n" ;
?>
/home/user
/home
user
```

Comment: i think that works with the current path with the file included in the path and not the string returned from getcwd()

Comment: ??? Why -2 points to my answer? How about explaining what I have written wrong instead of clicking an arrow down?

Comment: Sure, I understand. You could not even click twice the arrow down. So I wonder why all of a suddent two times -1 even though the answer IMHO is correct for you look for the "C" name of /A/B/C path, and basename( "/A/B/C" ) will return you "C" - that is what you need. Strange.

Comment: no idea why the downvotes either. Based on what OP is asking this is perfectly valid. given `$path='/var/www/folder2';` (which is exactly what getcwd might return), `basename($path);` would return `folder2`.

Comment: im confused about the usuage let me test it out though

Comment: Thank you guys for the moral support and up votes. I would understand why there could be -1 by someone making a mistake but -2 I saw was shocking.

Comment: Oh well yes no vote down this works perfectly as well for the actual question I asked although its easier to use the document root. But to answer my question directly this is correct as well.

Comment: Thanks Duice352. It is funny to have post marked as an answer and having -1 points :) Thanks again!

Comment: lol it is pretty funny but while both answers are a solution to the task i have to admit this is the direct answer to the question. Although it may not be the best practice for the particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Make include path relative to **_*DIR*_ or dirname(_*FILE*_)** in older PHP. Or to **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**. *NEVER TO CURRENT DIRECTORY!*

```
include(__DIR__.'/../../includes/nav.php'); // Folder 2 files
include(__DIR__.'/../includes/nav.php'); // Folder 1 files
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: doc root gotcha thanks for that.. but can i also get an answer on how to cut strings in that sense because i do see it being benificial along the road all i know is substr and counting but i want to cut based on where the slashes are or certain words

Comment: @Duice352 Not sure what you mean but learn regexp and the string functions. You need to! Anything you do in PHP, you'll bump into strings. There's not other way around them :)

Comment: this works perfectly btw. it says for me to wait two minutes.  and regexp seems very complicated any good resources that you can point me to.. the manual lacks examples of usage i learn best kinetically and visually.

Comment: @Duice352 Not sure what you need but look into explode() function and preg_split(). That should get you on the right track. These will break paths into arrays and then you can process them.

Comment: @Duice352 `basename` would get you the filename/last folder of a path. `dirname` would get you the path minus the filename/last folder. And for something as structured as a path with little variance in the folder/file description, regex is WAY overkill. You could just `explode('/', $path)` and have an array of each folder/filename.

Answer (score 0):

Please try::

```
if (basename(dirname(__FILE__)) = 'Folder2'){
    include('../../includes/nav.php');
}else{
    include('../includes/nav.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special variable

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

to list everything after the DNS name in the url.  The easiest thing to do at that point is probably to split it with the explode function using "/" as your delimiter, and remove the last element of the array (your php filename), then use implode to get the whole string back as a single variable.

That would give you your current directory from the web root.